# Can Redis be queried in a similar way to MySQL in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, redis

I currently have a standard Laravel/MySQL application setup, but it turns out we are going to need to create some sort of key value storage. Instead of creating some massive, archaic relational mess in MySQL, I was hoping to implement something along the lines of Redis and wanted to make sure I have the jist of what Redis does and if it is a fit before I spend a week flailing around.

Ideally, I would have a MySQL table with forms

```
id | form
1  | 'Contact'
2  | 'Header'
3  | 'Homepage - Side'
```

and leads come from these forms into another MySQL table

id  | timestamp            | status_id | form_id
   1   | 2014-01-01 14:13:23  | 1         | 1
   2   | 2014-01-02 14:13:23  | 1         | 2

then there would be a Redis key value store of the data related to leads..

```
key          | value         | lead_id
'email'      | '123@123.com' | 1
'name'       | 'Curly'       | 1
'best_time   | 'Evening'     | 2
'name'       | 'Moe'         | 2
'email'      | 'Larry'       | 3
```

My questions are:

- Would using a combination of MySQL/Redis be the right approach for this?
- Can I query/sort/filter the data from Redis as if it came from MySQL?

Comment: Redis documentation and exemples are numerous, you clearly have made no effort in reading these.
http://redis.io/topics/twitter-clone

Answer (score 2):

Redis is a very good key/value store, but it has its limitations. For one, everything hast to fit in memory. This makes it impractical for larger data sets. It's also a little difficult to work with unless you do things the Redis way, embrace its quirks and limitations.

Having some data in one database and some in another makes things especially awkward, so I'd avoid doing this unless you had no other option.

In your case what you probably need is a better document store than MySQL. You might consider CouchDB, MongoDB, or PostgreSQL which has fantastic JSON support. MySQL is massively trailing behind in terms of features of this sort.

If you need a schemaless database, maybe you need a database that supports that natively.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This was one of my initial thoughts but I was stubbornly hoping that marrying the two technologies (mySQL & Redis) was a mildly acceptable practice somewhere. It seems like it is done, but not how I am looking to do it. Based on your feedback, I should probably look into converting to a MEAN stack.

Comment: Yeah, the MEAN stack combination is pretty potent and definitely worth checking out.